# Link, name, caption and description missing in FBNativeDialogs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I just updated my iPhone app supporting iOS native sharing of Facebook SDK 3.1'. Previously, we were showing Sharing Popup where we can pass "link", "name", "caption", "description". But now in iOS native sharing popup, there is only one text input, "initialText".

[FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                                    **initialText**:@"Status message"
                                                                          image:nil
                                                                            url:nil
                                                                        handler:nil]

**How can we get the previous format(with "link", "name", "caption", "description") in iOS native sharing?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with a help of [Karthikeyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479092/karthikeyan)

I will send only link parameter in iOS 6. Suppose the link is "http://example.com/sharingpage"

And then in the web page, we will change dynamically the following parameters. 
og:title
og:description
og:url
og:image

after we share the link via iOS 6 native sharing popup, facebook itself will take the following values from the link and show it in our post, which we shared in Facebook wall.